# javascript ie vs the other browsers - ie not defined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a simple example that utilizes tinymce rich text editor. If I browse it in anything other than IE it works perfectly fine. However, if I browse with IE it says tinymce not defined. Is there a way to make it work in IE **without using an onload** event (which apparently works with IE)? Any insight?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.write(" \
<html><head><title></title> \
<script type='text/javascript' src='tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'><\/script> \
  <script type='text/javascript'> \
    tinyMCE.init({ \
        mode : 'textareas', \
        theme : 'simple' \
    }); \
<\/script>   \
 \
</head><body><textarea>test</textarea></body></html> \
");
</script>
```

Comment: Please post you code in text. Not an image of your code. Why do you require a `document.write`? You could use `onload` for all browsers

Comment: Any reason to not use JQuery (`$(...)`) to simplify initialization? (no comments on rendering page with `.write`... I assume it is to practice triple encoding skill).

Comment: this is a result of a very long and dynamic process where html is generated and sent back to browser via ajax and then .write to screen. JQuery isn't available for this scenario unfortunately and neither is onload.

Comment: Some times when you try to write the `<script` you have issues because the browser can take it as script and not as text, try to write it as `"<scr" + "ipt"` and see whats happens.

Comment: separating scr+ipt didn't work for me